# SQL Handle holidays set by user weekly on a week table calendar

Tags: sql-server

Let's just say I have something called X which is calculated on the formula

```
WorkDaysLeftInTheWeek * X
```

Where WorkDaysLeftInTheWeek

```
 WorkDaysLeftInTheWeek = 5 - TotalHolidaysThisWeek - DayIndex
```

DayIndex is an index for each work day and starts from 0.

Basically if no holidays then

```
Monday = 0
Tuesday = 1
Wednesday = 2
Thursday = 3
Friday = 4
```

Why you ask?

My X value is 6.

If no holidays then my week has 5 days, this value has to decrease every day to calculate the amount of units to supply to some production unit.

Here is an example

Monday

1. Production Unit needs 10000 units for this week
2. X is 6
3. No holidays this week set by user, so WorkDays is 5 for this week
4. So 10000 / ((5 - 0) * 6) = 333,33. That's the amount of units to supply on monday

Tuesday

1. Production Unit needs 10000 units for this week
2. X is 6
3. No holidays this week set by user, so WorkDays is 5 for this week
4. So 10000 / ((5 - 1) * 6) = 416 That's the amount of units to supply on Tuesday

if all goes well on Friday which is the last work day the result will be

10000 / ((5 - 4) * 6) = 1666 units.

Of course the units needed will decrease, but this is static just to show how it works.

So what have i done to achieve this so far?

first I created a table

```
CREATE TABLE hCalendarios
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Week INT, -- The Week Number
    Day NVARCHAR(20), -- Name of the weekday
    IsHoliday BIT
)

--Insert initial data
INSERT INTO hCalendarios VALUES 
(NULL,'Monday',0),(NULL,'Tuesday',0),(NULL,'Wednesday',0),(NULL,'Thursday',0),(NULL,'Friday',0)
```

Let's just say the user already had set the week 30 with a holiday
Here is the result of table

```
Id  Week  Day       IsHoliday
1   30    Monday    0
2   30    Tuesday   0
3   30    Wednesday 1
4   30    Thursday  0
5   30    Friday    0
```

With this data I know which day is holiday without saving dates just by using the Week day and compare the name of the week day

Now here is my function

```
GO
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'GetDaysLeftCurrentWeek') 
    AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION GetDaysLeftCurrentWeek
GO
CREATE FUNCTION GetDaysLeftCurrentWeek (@Days TINYINT)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS BEGIN

    -- Variables
    DECLARE
        @CurrentWeekDay TINYINT, 
        @TotalHolidays TINYINT,
        @IsSameWeek BIT
    -- End Variables

    -- Initialize Variables 
    SET @IsSameWeek = 
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM hCalendarios WHERE Week = DATEPART(week, GETDATE())) = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END

    -- Check if holidays are set on current week
    IF(@IsSameWeek = 1)     
    BEGIN
        -- Total holidays on current week
        SET @TotalHolidays = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hCalendarios WHERE IsHoliday = 1)
        -- Total work days on the week
        SET @Days = @Days - @TotalHolidays

        -- Get current day of the week
        SET @CurrentWeekDay = (SELECT RowNum
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id ASC) - 1 AS RowNum FROM hCalendarios
            WHERE IsHoliday = 0 
        ) X
        WHERE Day = (SELECT DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())))

        -- Check if today is a holiday
        IF(@CurrentWeekDay IS NULL)
        BEGIN

            -- Handle when 1st day is holiday
            IF((SELECT DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())) <> 'Monday')        
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @cnt INT
                -- Get the Id of the current day
                SET @cnt = (SELECT Id FROM hCalendarios WHERE Day = (SELECT DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())))

               -- Decrement the Id from the current day until one work day is found
                WHILE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM hCalendarios WHERE IsHoliday = 0 AND Id = @cnt)
                BEGIN         
                   SET @cnt = @cnt - 1;
                   IF(@cnt = 1)
                   BEGIN
                       BREAK
                   END
                END;

                -- Decrement by one so 1st work day starts from 0
                SET @CurrentWeekDay = @cnt - 1
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN 
                -- Set monday to 0 if it's holiday 
                SET @CurrentWeekDay = 0
            END
        END

        RETURN @Days - @CurrentWeekDay
    END

     -- Get current day of the week
    SET @CurrentWeekDay = (SELECT RowNum
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id ASC) - 1 AS RowNum FROM hCalendarios
        WHERE IsHoliday = 0 
    ) X
    WHERE Day = (SELECT DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())))

    RETURN @Days - @CurrentWeekDay

END
```

To sum it up, this function doesn't really need to recieve a parameter tho cause it will always use 5 as static days in the week

So the steps are

1. Check if there are holidays on the current week.
2. If not just return the totaldays - the dayIndex which is the currentday
3. If it's same week subtract the total holidays on the days
4. Now to get the current weekday when there is a holiday, I have to order by row number the total work days on the week cause this will keep the same dayIndex sequence, just less days, because in the end, the last work day it has to return 1
5. Now first I handle when the current day is a holiday, because if so I need to use the index from the previous work day.
6. Let's handle Monday first, if monday is a holiday, just return the total work days in the week
7. Now to get the last work day, I use a while loop which basically if it reaches monday and no work day was found it just breaks the loop

now here is a problem, the loop part is not 100% accurate if it reaches monday without any work days.

Plus there is also to handle when monday and the next day is a holiday and so on but i can't figure out how to handle all of this without going too deep into it.

**EDIT**

I posted the final result as an answer for whoever wants to use my function in a similar situation

Comment: "the loop part is not 100% accurate if it reaches monday without any work days." -- What EXACTLY does this mean?

Comment: It means I have not handled it in case this situation happens nor have i tested towards it

Comment: Why haven't you?

Comment: Because I lacked time and I'm still working on it. I posted my problem not because of that but because I wasn't sure how to handle when the day after monday is a holiday or even also the day after and so on 'cause I need at least one work day for the loop to actually work properly

Comment: @nicomp I posted my final result. This solves everything

Answer (score 0):

I finally done it! It handles every possible day or period of days that are marked as holiday by the user.

If there is a holiday in the middle of the week and there was already a work day at the start, then the index of that work day is used.

Whenever the week starts with 1 or more days in a row as holidays, then 0 is used

Here is the final result. With this you can make a simple holiday or inactivity period weekly calendar that is set by the User

```
GO
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'GetDaysLeftCurrentWeek') 
    AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION GetDaysLeftCurrentWeek
GO
CREATE FUNCTION GetDaysLeftCurrentWeek (@Days TINYINT)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS BEGIN

    -- Variables
    DECLARE
        @CurrentWeekDay TINYINT, 
        @TotalHolidays TINYINT,
        @IsSameWeek BIT,
        @WorkDaysLeft TINYINT
    -- End Variables

    -- Initialize Variables 

    -- Total holidays on current week
    SET @TotalHolidays = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hCalendarios WHERE IsHoliday = 1)
    -- Total work days on the week
    SET @WorkDaysLeft = @Days - @TotalHolidays

    SET @IsSameWeek = 
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM hCalendarios WHERE Week = DATEPART(week, GETDATE())) = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END

    -- Get current day of the week
    SET @CurrentWeekDay = (SELECT RowNum
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id ASC) - 1 AS RowNum FROM hCalendarios
        WHERE IsHoliday = 0
    ) X
    WHERE Day = (SELECT DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())))


    -- if no holidays in this week, return work days left
    IF(@IsSameWeek = 0)     
    BEGIN    
        RETURN @WorkDaysLeft - @CurrentWeekDay
    END

    -- Get current day of the week
    SET @CurrentWeekDay = 
     -- Filter the data set by current day
        (
            SELECT RowNum
            FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    *
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT 
                        *,  
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id ASC) - 1 AS RowNum FROM hCalendarios
                    WHERE IsHoliday = 0
                ) DerivedTableWorkDaysOnly
                UNION -- Add holidays to the dataset
                SELECT  
                    *,  
                    (
                        -- If week starts with holidays just set them to 0 otherwise get previous highest workday row number
                        SELECT 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN MAX(RowNum) IS NULL THEN 0  
                                ELSE MAX(RowNum) 
                            END 
                        FROM 
                        (
                            -- Get all work days before the current day
                            SELECT 
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) - 1 RowNum 
                            FROM hCalendarios Cal1 WHERE IsHoliday = 0  AND Cal1.Id < Cal2.Id 
                        ) DerivedTablePreviousWorkDay
                    ) AS RowNum 
                FROM hCalendarios Cal2
                WHERE IsHoliday = 1

                ) DerivedTableIndexedDays
            WHERE Day = (SELECT DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()))
        )

        RETURN @WorkDaysLeft - @CurrentWeekDay

END
```